# Partialview not returning model for a sortedlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am very, very new to MVC, so please bear with my question, I have to work with the following structure.
I have the following models, Facility and Address. Facility contains a SortedList of Address, I have reduced the number of properties for clarity,

```
public class AppFacility
{
    public AppFacility()
    {
        this.Addresses = new SortedList<string, AppAddress>();
    }

    public SortedList<string, AppAddress> Addresses { get; set; }

    [DisplayNameAttribute("Facility ID")]
    public int FacilityID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Facility Name is a required field")]
    [DisplayNameAttribute("Facility Name")]
    public string FacilityName { get; set; }

    [DisplayNameAttribute("Doing Business As")]
    public string Dba { get; set; }

    [DisplayNameAttribute("Nbr. Of Employees")]
    public int NbrOfEmployees { get; set; }
}

public class AppAddress
{
    [DisplayNameAttribute("City")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [DisplayNameAttribute("State")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [DisplayNameAttribute("Street Name")]
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
 }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult FacilityCreate(AppFacility objFacility)
    {
        facilityManager = new Manager.AppFacilityManager();

            if (facilityManager.InsertAppFacility(objFacility))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("FacilityInfo", new { id = objFacility.FacilityID });
            }

        return View((AppFacility)Session["FacilityObject"]);
    }
```

View:
FacilityCreate

```
@model Model.CORE.BO.AppFacility
<table width="100%" align="center" border="0" class="SectionTables">
<tr>
    <td class="SubtitleHeader">
        Facility
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="SubtitleHeader1">
        Enter Facility Information
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        @Html.Partial(p_CreateEditAppFacility, Model)         
    </td>         
</tr>
```

Partial view: 
p_CreateEditAppFacility:
This contains the p_CreateEditAddress partial view as well.

```
@model Model.CORE.BO.AppFacility 
@using (Html.BeginForm("FacilityCreate", "Form", FormMethod.Post, 
new { id = "saveForm",     name = "saveForm" }))
{      
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="main">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Operator Information</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Facility Name (Business Name of Operator to Appear): ")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FacilityName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FacilityName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Owner's Business Name (If different from Business Name of Operator): ")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dba)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dba) 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("No of Employees:")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NbrOfEmployees)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NbrOfEmployees)
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Address Information</legend> 
       @{ 
int i = 0;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Model.CORE.BO.AppAddress> addressRow in Model.Addresses)
{

        <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Partial(p_CreateEditAddress, addressRow.Value, new ViewDataDictionary(Html.ViewDataContainer.ViewData) { TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Format("objFacility.Addresses[{0}]", i) } })       
        </div>
    i++;
}
    }
  </fieldset>

    <p>            
        <input id="SaveFacility" name="SaveInfo" type="submit" value="Save Information" />
    </p>
</div>
```

}

PartialView:
p_CreateEditAddress

```
@model Model.CORE.BO.AppAddress
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StreetName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StreetName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StreetName)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)
</div>
```

My question is that in the Controller the objFacility.Addresses does not get the values entered for the model AppAddress, it is always null. The AppFacility gets populated though. 
The html behind looks like this for p_CreateEditAddress

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input class="text-box single-line" 
id="objFacility_Addresses_0__StreetName"  
name="objFacility.Addresses[0].StreetName" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" 
data-valmsg-for="objFacility.Addresses[0].StreetName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Please help.

Comment: Is there any reason you are setting the objFacility prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your Partial View call to take the correct prefix. You don't give it the Model name as the default model binder will be creating an instance of your class and looking for fields that match the names of the items in the `Request.Form` collection. It knows nothing about the variable name you've gave your model, just the properties of your Model's class.

Try this (I put line breaks in for readability):

```
@Html.Partial(p_CreateEditAddress, addressRow.Value,
    new ViewDataDictionary(Html.ViewDataContainer.ViewData) {
        TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo { 
            HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Format("Addresses[{0}]", i) 
        } 
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had tried the way you mentioned earlier with no luck.

Comment: @user1424052 Ah okay no problems. Out of interest, why is it a `SortedList`? I think that could be an issue, trying to index a sorted list :). Can you change it to a `List`?

Comment: Sorry for my later reply. Changed everything to List and it works perfectly fine. Thank you very much for your reply. Could you throw some insight into why sortedlist would not work?

Comment: @user1424052 No problems! Glad I could help. It won't have worked because you used a `string` as the Key for the `SortedList`, but the properties in the view are indexed via integer `[0]`, maybe the model binder had difficulty trying to assign those values to the `SortedList`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the generated HTML is not proper for model binding.

It should not be `objFacility.Addresses[0].StreetName` but `Addresses[0].StreetName`.

Comment: <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="text-box single-line" id="Addresses_0__StreetName" name="Addresses[0].StreetName" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Addresses[0].StreetName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>